# How does OpenCV represent a line with 2 two values?

Tags: c++, opencv, line, hough-transform

In OpenCV's `imgproc` module, there exists a function called `HoughLines` which takes a binary image, some other parameters, and returns a vector of `Vec2f`'s which are pairs of floating point values.

These values are supposed to represent the lines found in the binary image, but I'm struggling to understand how.

The first value of each pair, the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines) states, is the distance from the origin. The distance from the origin to what? The line? If so, which part of the line?

The second value of `Vec2f`, they say, is the "line rotation angle in radians". Rotation angle relative to what axis?

Ideally, I would like to convert this representation of a line into something I can work with, such as the good, old cartesian `y = mx + c`. If not, I would at least like to be able to find every point that lies on the line represented by `Vec2f`.

Any ideas on how I can achieve either of the two above? Or, what do the `Vec2f[0]` and `Vec2f[1]` values *precisely* mean?

Comment: Read up on polar coordinates. The line is defined by the origin and (r, theta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is given in a link the documentation you point to [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm). The line is defined in a parametric way, i.e under the form `x cos(a) + y sin(a) = r`. Contrary to cartesian form, it allows to express vertical lines. Thus, if you don' have vertical lines (i.e sin(a) is never null) the cartesian form in your case is:

```
y = -  ( cos (Vec2f[1]) / sin (Vec2f[1] ) x - Vec2f[0]
```